# How to call a function in a StatefulWidget from another StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call a function(addGeoPoint) from Map class in another function named onDragEnd of the class SwipeButton both of which is are stateful.

```
class Map extends StatefulWidget {
//Some Code
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
//Some Functions

void addGeoPoint() async{
}
```

File 2

```
class SwipeButton extends StatefulWidget {

// Some Code

  @override
  SwipeButtonState createState() => SwipeButtonState();
}

class SwipeButtonState extends State<SwipeButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

// Some functions
void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
   // I want to call the addGeoPoint() function here 

}

}
```

To do so, I tried creating an instance of the class Map as `Map mapScreen = new Map` and then access the function using `mapScreen.addGeoPoint()` but, I achieved no success. Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VoidCallBacks](https://alligator.io/flutter/widget-communication/) to communicate between Widgets:

Map:

```
class Map extends StatefulWidget {
//Some Code
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
//Some Functions

void addGeoPoint() async{
  //do things
}

Widget buildSwipeButton() {
    ...
    ...
    return SwipeButton(
      onAddGeoPoint: addGeoPoint,
    );
}
```

SwipeButton:

```
class SwipeButton extends StatefulWidget {

final VoidCallback onAddGeopoint;

SwipeButton({this.onAddGeoPoint});

// Some Code

  @override
  SwipeButtonState createState() => SwipeButtonState();
}

class SwipeButtonState extends State<SwipeButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

// Some functions
void _onDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
   // I want to call the addGeoPoint() function here 
   widget.onAddGeoPoint();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your widget like this

```
class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callback;

  YourWidget({@required this.textButton});

  @override
  YourWidgetState createState() => YourWidgetState();
}
```

then you can pass de function like this in your stateful parent

```
YourWidget(
   callback: (){}
)
```

ant then you can use in YourWidget like this in other widget or other function

```
widget.callback()
```